# Problems in focusing when calibrating a DSLR

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, stereo-3d, photogrammetry

I am using 2 `CANON EOS60d`s as a stereo setup to do `Photogrammetry`. I am using `OpenCV` to calibrate both the cameras using a high precision `Circlegrid` calibration pattern. I am using a signal generator to trigger both cameras at the same time, earlier i tried to use Gphoto2 to trigger them but there was bit of time delay, so i relied on signal generator to trigger them.

The problem in the calibration is that, the cameras lose focus even if i move the pattern a little bit, so i am getting incorrect results, since i m not moving the pattern too much between frames(We have to cover entire field of view of cameras in calibration and all the euler angles should change). To prevent it i have to increase aperture to increase the DOF(depth of field) for both cameras, and this further causes me to decrease shutter speed. The problem in decreasing shutter speed is that it will cause shaky pictures if the calibration pattern moves.

If anybody has any experience calibrating DSLRs, and can give me some ideas about calibration, i would be grateful.

Comment: More light, so you can have shorter exposure to compensate?

Comment: I tried it, because the calibration plate i am using is black with white dots, It reflects lot of light, and there are false detections.

Comment: Well, you spelled out the solution yourself: make a gray/black calibration target, rather than a white/black one.

Comment: Actually i m not making the calibration pattern myself. I am using the one available in the market, because the one i have has a precision of 0.001mm.

Comment: @FrancescoCallari Black targets yield IMO inferior results for most algorithms. In the black area you don't have any information in the form of photons. Your algorithm basically just averages the sensor-noise. Its far better to use white circular targets. There are some research papers on this topic which you might want to read.

Comment: Be happy to, send links please (@fgcallari on twitter)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem in the calibration is that, the cameras lose focus even if i move the pattern a little bit, so i am getting incorrect results.

What do you mean by incorrect results? It is not a problem for circular targets, if they're a litte bit out of focus.

> We have to cover entire field of view of cameras in calibration and all the euler angles should change

This should be valid for the entire dataset, not necessary from image to image.

> To prevent it i have to increase aperture to increase the DOF(depth of field) for both cameras, and this further causes me to decrease shutter speed. The problem in decreasing shutter speed is that it will cause shaky pictures if the calibration pattern moves.

Don't decrease shutter speed. It depends on your focal length, but usually something higher than 1/320 or 1/240 is not a good choice. It's beeter to stay out of focus as an still image than blurry (distorted) targets due to movement.

DSLR Calibration is a common task and usually works well in practice. However we need more information about your setup in order to provide help.

What is your:
- Camera
- Lens
- Shutter Speed
- Aperture
- ISO
- Measurement Volume

And finally, what are your Results and what do you expect?